# How to access WebService stored on server using jquery in asp.net application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I am working on an asp.net application.
I have created a WebServices which has WebMethod Called "BindCategory" which returns List of News-Category.The WebService in my application as :

```
namespace MobileNewsAppication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for MobileServices
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 

    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class MobileServices : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        public class NewsCategory
        {
            public long Category_ID { get; set; }
            public string Category_Name { get; set; }
            public string QFlag { get; set; }
        }

        [WebMethod)]
        public NewsCategory[] BindCategory()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            List<NewsCategory> details = new List<NewsCategory>();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AllCategory_Select", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    NewsCategory Category = new NewsCategory();
                    Category.Category_Name = dtrow["Category_Name"].ToString();
                    Category.Category_ID = Convert.ToInt64(dtrow["Category_ID"].ToString());
                    details.Add(Category);
                }

            }
            return details.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Now i have deployed this Webservice on service.
Now i have created another asp.net application and i am trying to access that WebService which is on Server.
My Code to access the Web Method as:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js">  
  </script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://webcall.com/MobileServices.asmx/BindCategory",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: true,
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });

        function OnSuccess(data) {

            $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                $("#ulCategory").append("<li>" + value.Category_Name + "</li>");
            })

        }
        function OnError(data) {
            alert('fail');
        }

    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div style="width:200px;height:600px; background-color:#e8e8e8; float:left;">
            Category
         <ul id="ulCategory">
         </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am unable to access that WebMethod which is on server.I have also added a webreference of that webservice which is on server but It returns to error function.
Please Help me Here.

Answer (score 1):

It says `UseHttpGet = true` , However you are making a `POST` call in your Jquery method.

Answer (score 0):

is the syntax correct? (sry i don't remember for sure.) after the $.ajax call there's a semicolon. should it be a comma, then commas between the callback functions? or can they be separated like that?

or like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "etc",
dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        ...
    } ...
```

also, do you have to send data to the callbacks? (success: OnSuccess(data)) or is that automatic?